# Клонирование объекта

Tags: javascript, объекты, клонирование

```
var user = {
  name: "Вася",
  age: 30
};
var clone = {}; // новый пустой объект
// скопируем в него все свойства user
for (var key in user) {
  clone[key] = user[key];
}
```

Вопрос относительно строки `clone[key] = user[key]`.
По идее, `user[key]` содержит только значение(Вася и 30) свойств `name` и `age`, а в переменной `key` хранится имя свойства?
Но в результате клонирования скопировались и имена переменных.
Как так вышло?

Comment: Вы же написали clone[key] = user[key]. . Это означает, что к объекту clone добавляется свойство с именем, хранимым в переменной key.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: @VladfromMoscow , то есть в  `user[key]` хранится и имя свойства и значение?

Comment: @ra.chobanyan `clone[key]` - вы создаете поле с именем `key` в  объекте `clone` и в которое кладете значение из `user[key]`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , спасибо. Понял все.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А как Вы хотели?
Клон должен быть идентичен по определению.

`key` - имя свойства (`name`, `age`); `user[key]` - значение свойства (`Вася`, `30`).

Копировать объект проще так:

```js
var user = {
  name: "Вася",
  age: 30
};

let clone = Object.assign(user);

console.dir(clone);
```